# What does "all a little worse for wear after a day of carousing" mean here?

Tags: meaning, literature

I would like to know what "all a little worse for wear after a day of carousing" means in the following sentences:

> It is a few moments before the waitress regains consciousness. She is,
> it appears, uninjured, but whatever she has seen out there has struck
> her nearly mute. The most they can get from her are low moans,
> wordless nonsense.
>
> ‘I sent her over to the Folly for a couple more bottles of champagne,’
> the head waitress – only twenty or so herself – says helplessly.
>
> There is a palpable hush in the marquee. The guests are looking among
> the throng of people for their loved ones, to check that they are safe
> and accounted for. But it is difficult to spot anyone among the
> seething crowd, **all a little worse for wear after a day of carousing**.
> It is difficult, too, because of the structure of this
> state-of-the-art marquee: the dance floor in one tent, the bar in
> another, the main dining section in the largest.

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 13

This is a thriller novel published in 2020 in the United Kingdom. One hundred and fifty guests gathered at some remote and deserted fictional islet called Inis an Amplóra off the coast of the island of Ireland to celebrate the wedding between Jules (a self-made woman running an online magazine called *The Download*) and Will (a celebrity appearing in a TV show program called *Survive the Night*). The wedding ceremony is held at the Folly, which is a renovated castle. On the wedding night, after several times of blackout, a waitress screams outside before entering the marquee, the party venue installed on the island, and guests are now all gathered to see what happened, in front of the fainted waitress.

In this part, I am wondering what "all a little worse for wear after a day of carousing" means.
I looked up "worse for wear" and found that it means to be "drunk," so I wonder whether it would be all right to understand that *everyone (=all)* had their minds *a little muddled (= a little worse for wear)* after they had spent one day while *drinking and playing (=carousing)*.

In short, I am wondering whether "all" means "everyone" here, and whether it would be okay to see that "worse for wear" is the second reason why they find it difficult to spot anyone among the crowd, the first reason being the "seething" (=fast-moving) of the crowd.

Or perhaps, does "all" functions like "all the more"...? I am confused.

Comment: Yes, all means everyone.  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-worse-for-wear    https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carouse

Comment: All [of the crowd] are a little drunk after having had plenty to drink all day.

Comment: Dear @RonaldSole and Kate Bunting, thank you very much for the explanations. So it means everyone was a little drunk after having enjoyed their drinks throughout the day. I sincerely appreciate your help. :)